# ubuntu 21.04 desktop does not provide nvidia drivers for Sony VPCCW1S1E/W

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my Sony VPCCW1S1E/W notebook. It has a Nvidia GT 230M video card, as the output of lshw shows:

```
   *-display
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: GT216M [GeForce GT 230M]
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        version: a2
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
        resources: irq:32 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

However, when I try to install Nvidia drivers, nothing happens.
That is, if I try from Additional Drivers section inside Software and Updates, I get "No additional drivers available" message.
Moreover, the command

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

has no output.
So, aren't drivers for my video card  anymore provided in Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: The `nouveau` driver is a Nvidia supported driver, and the preferred driver for many older nvidia cards. It's been a number of years since Nvidia embraced `nouveau` as supported.

Comment: `nouveau` is indeed the only driver available for that card. Nvidia dropped support for it a long time ago.

Comment: However with nouveau driver I cannot set brightness level neither with the function keys, nor with the slider in the drop down menu. I tried mx linux an it allowed to install nvidia driver for my card and to set brightness level.

Comment: Set up keyboard shortcuts to do it using whatever keystrokes you prefer (even the FN keys your laptop uses is possible).  I recall writing an answer on this site many cycles ago on how to do it (it wasn't with GNOME, but LXQt/Lubuntu... so it's of no use to you with GNOME as the command I used altered brightness used Qt5/LXQt, but the concept is the same; just command & how shortcut is entered into OS needs to be the GNOME based).

Comment: @guiverc If I cannot set it using slider in Power section I am afraid that no keyboard shorcuts will work.

Comment: Why not?   The question I answered was because a user was having trouble getting what they wanted so my answer used brightness/backlight/(another I forget) adjustments to get around whatever the issue was and achieve whatever the OP wanted with their question. My answer was mostly written as 'how to' so they could work out which achieved wanted result, then code the keys to execute the required function... A programmed script run commands that achieved the result, & keyboard shortcut(s) made it easy to live with. The slider didn't work then, commands did!

Comment: That said, if you aren't comfortable with the solution suggested by @guiverc and MX Linux works for you (because it runs a very old kernel that still supports the Nvidia 340 driver needed for your card), why don't you just use MX Linux?

Comment: @guiverc I am not a completely linux/ubuntu inexperienced user but what you suggest require a little more study than what I would like to have to do with a user friendly linux distribution.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I am trying several linux distributions to see which one fits better my needs, and I am giving Ubuntu a chance. I would like just to mention that Ubuntu 20.04.2 runs a kernel which supports the 340 driver, so I suppose it's definitively not a thing to blame MX Linux for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you can get Nvidia 230M working on Ubuntu 21.04 by installing Nvidia 340 driver from [special *nvidia-legacy* PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy/+packages?field.name_filter=340&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=hirsute). Open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

then reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using this driver and adding acpi_backlight=video to /etc/default/grub  (that is GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video") has done the job and now I can set brightness both using function keys or the slider.

Comment: Great! So you can accept this answer by clicking on grey checkmark on the left side of answer. Long live to your VAIO. As F13-owner I can say that they are great.

Comment: Sorry, before I forgot to mark the answer, I just fixed it.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I used it on my DELL Vostro 3500 laptop. Other ways of getting and installing the NVIDIA 340.108 driver always resulted in failure as the dot run file from NVIDIA always claimed the nouveau driver was there when I had run the "book" commands to remove it. If I had known about the answer given above I would have saved literally tens of hours. John